# Jquery - Locating all elements of same class, hide div that does not have specific rel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, hide

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="mydiv" rel="1">test one</div>
<div class="mydiv" rel="2">test two</div>
<div class="mydiv" rel="3">test three</div>
<div class="mydiv" rel="2">test three</div>
```

My goal is to use jQuery to hide all div elements that **DO NOT** have a rel of, say, 1.

The rel value will be dynamically generated. So I would like to hide any div.mydiv where the rel != 1.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/). `$('.mydiv[rel!=1]').hide()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiding all div's which have a rel value of anything except one is as simple as this:

```
$(".myDiv[rel!=1]").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.mydiv').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('rel') != 1;
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

$(".myDiv[rel!=1]").hide(); 
is proper answer to your question. 
OR you can do this way as well

```
$('div.mydiv').not('div[rel="1"]').hide();
```